# How can I export a list of users including their Content Profile data?

Tags: views, 6, users

I need to export the user list including Content Profile data to excel. I tried a couple of modules (like "views data export") but I can't get them to work and the documentation doesn't exist...

I understand that the best starting point is views (I created a query with the wanted fields), but I don't know where to go from there.

Can you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Drupal is this?

Comment: D6, see tag (was in title at time of comment) ;)